# Aerospike connection errors

Tags: aerospike

We run Aerospike server 3.5.15-1 on Ubuntu 14.04 and periodically getting server connection errors from PHP clients ([-1]Unable to connect to server). PHP client version 3.4.1. We run PHP 5.3 clients from a separate server node. Connections created from php-fpm.

There are no any corresponding errors in the server logs and server didn't have to be restarted. So, the problem seem to be on the client side.

This application creates up to 400 simultaneous connections to Aerospike. We use r3.xlarge EC2 instance and server has plenty of available resources.

We followed Aerospike tuning documentation and tried updating proto-fd and recommended OS patameters on the server, but it didn't help

```
   proto-fd-max 100000
   proto-fd-idle-ms 15000
```

That's how we initialize and use Aerospike:

```
$opts = array(Aerospike::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT => 1250,Aerospike::OPT_WRITE_TIMEOUT => 5000);
$this->db = new Aerospike($config, false, $opts);

//set key
$aero_key = $this->db->initKey($this->keyspace, $this->table, $key);
$aero_value = array("value" => $value);
$status = $this->db->put($aero_key, $aero_value, $ttl, $options);

//get key
$aero_key = $this->db->initKey($this->keyspace, $this->table, $key);
$status = $this->db->get($aero_key, $result);
```

Aerospike server stats before the disconnect:

`Aug 27 2015 19:32:50 GMT: INFO (info): (thr_info.c::4828)    trans_in_progress: wr 0 prox 0 wait 0 ::: q 0 ::: bq 0 ::: iq 0 ::: dq 0 : fds - proto (237, 16073516, 16073279) : hb (0, 0, 0) : fab (16, 16, 0)
Aug 27 2015 19:33:00 GMT: INFO (info): (thr_info.c::4828)    trans_in_progress: wr 0 prox 0 wait 0 ::: q 0 ::: bq 0 ::: iq 0 ::: dq 0 : fds - proto (334, 16076516, 16076182) : hb (0, 0, 0) : fab (16, 16, 0)
Aug 27 2015 19:33:10 GMT: INFO (info): (thr_info.c::4828)    trans_in_progress: wr 0 prox 0 wait 0 ::: q 0 ::: bq 0 ::: iq 1 ::: dq 0 : fds - proto (288, 16079478, 16079190) : hb (0, 0, 0) : fab (16, 16, 0)
Aug 27 2015 19:33:20 GMT: INFO (info): (thr_info.c::4828)    trans_in_progress: wr 0 prox 0 wait 0 ::: q 0 ::: bq 0 ::: iq 0 ::: dq 0 : fds - proto (131, 16082477, 16082346) : hb (0, 0, 0) : fab (16, 16, 0)
Aug 27 2015 19:33:30 GMT: INFO (info): (thr_info.c::4828)    trans_in_progress: wr 0 prox 0 wait 0 ::: q 0 ::: bq 0 ::: iq 0 ::: dq 0 : fds - proto (348, 16084665, 16084317) : hb (0, 0, 0)`

Comment: Do you mind updating the question? I can't tell what the problem is - a server crash or failing to connect from the clients? It seems like you have a crash but you're not stating it other than in one line. Are your clients running on separate nodes? What versions of the PHP client in son them?

Comment: @RonenBotzer There are no any corresponding errors in the server log and server didn't have to be restarted. So, the problem seem to be on the client side. Connections created from php-fpm. We have a single server instance. We run PHP 5.3 clients from a separate server node. Connections created from php-fpm.

Comment: Adding a link to the Aerospike discussion forum that has a duplicate of this question: https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/connection-errors-from-php-client/1719

Answer (score 1):

From the log segment, we can see that there are around 300 client connections open on the node at any one time, well under the 100000 limit in proto-fd-max.

If you are using multicast for heartbeats (and I think you are), the heartbeats of 0 are fine.

I expect that you have already looked at this, but are you able to check network connectivity between the client and server *at* the time of the failure?  I know that under normal conditions, the client and the server happily coexist, but at the time of the failure, do you see any basic connectivity problems?

Do you happen to have other applications installed on the client machine?  Do they have any similar failures, possibly at the time of the Aerospike client problems?

Do you have the client installed on more than one server?  Do you maybe only see the connectivity errors on one of the servers?

I know you have already been looking at this, so I apologize if I am covering topics that you have already reviewed.

Thank you for your time,

-DM

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let's continue this discussion at [discuss.aerospike.com/t/connection-errors-from-php-client/1719](http://discuss.aerospike.com/t/connection-errors-from-php-client/1719)